# is there any way to restore predefined schema to mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, restore

I'm beginner with mongoDB. i want to know is there any way to load predefined schema to mongoDB? ( for example like cassandra that use .cql file for this purpose)

If there is, please intruduce some document about structure of that file and way for restoring.

If there is not, how i can create an index only one time when I create a collection. I think it is wrong if i create index every time I call insert method or run my program.

p.s: I have a multi-threaded program that every thread insert and update my mongo collection. I want to create index only one time.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you actually asking here? Is it that you want to bulk load or restore a collection and only build an index when that is complete? Have you tried dropping the indexes and then only creating at the end of your processing?

Comment: i want to know is there anyway i define key or index before running my program? for example in cassandra we have .cql file and restore it for creating schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an index on a collection you need to use [ensureIndex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/) command. You need to only call it once to create an index on a collection.

If you call `ensureIndex` repeatedly with the same arguments, only the first call will create an index, all subsequent calls will have no effect.

So if you know what indexes you're going to use for your database, you can create a script that will call that command.

An example insert_index.js file that creates 2 indexes for `collA` and `collB` collections:

```
db.collA.ensureIndex({ a : 1});
db.collB.ensureIndex({ b : -1});
```

You can call it from a shell like this:

```
mongo --quiet localhost/dbName insert_index.js
```

This will create those indexes on a database named `dbName` on your localhost. It's worth noticing that if your database and/or collections are not yet created, this will create both the database and the collections for which you're adding the indexes.

**Edit**

To clarify a little bit. MongoDB is schemaless so you can't restore it's schema.
You can only create indexes and collections (by using [createCollection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/) helper).

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is basically schemaless so there is no definition of a schema or namespaces to be restored.

In the case of indexes, these can be created at any time. There does not need to be a collection present or even the required fields for the index as this will all be sorted out as the collections are created and when documents are inserted that matches the defined fields.

Commands to create an index are generally the same with each implementation language, for example:

```js
db.collection.ensureIndex({ a: 1, b: -1 })
```

Will define the index on the target collection in the target database that will reference field "a" and field "b", the latter in descending order. This will happen even if the collection or even the database does not exist as yet, or in fact will establish a blank namespace in that case.

Subsequent calls to the same index creation method do not actually re-create the index. Where the same index is specified to one that already exists it is effectively skipped as a "no-operation".

As such, you can simply feed all your required index creation statements at application startup and anything that is not already present will be created. Anything that already exists will be left alone.

Comment: thanks for your help. :) i was worry that coding this way be wrong.